# implementing pinch zoom inside scroll view

Tags: android, eclipse, scrollview, pinchzoom

I have few images inside scroll view, i want to implement pinch zoom or double tap zooming inside scroll view so that all the 10 or 11 images inside scroll view get zoomed like how it happens in a pdf viewer android app. can anyone please help me? 
Thank you

Comment: i tried implementing it for a single image in a sample app by the concept of matrix,bitmap..etc but was not sure about the exact code of the bitmap. So was confused.

Comment: ok..have you tried for TouchImageView instead of using normal imageview

Comment: No, i have no idea of that..can u please give me a detailed description or a code sample of that?

Comment: https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView see this link..